# Feature explanation with SHAP

Tags: machine-learning, shapley-value

I need to have a feature explanation of a predictor. I've read about SHAP values, but it seems I have to make coalitions with the features and make a prediction with every one of them. I have $100$ features which lead to $2^{100}$ predictions, so SHAP seems impossible to me.

Is there something I didn't understand about it? or at least is there a simplified SHAP or something like that?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'feature explanation of a predictor'?

Comment: I meant I wanted to know the impact of every feature in a prediction with kNN. The problem is I can't use that library because I'm doing it with MATLAB and I have to program it. I've seen the code in the SHAP library but it's a bit confusing for me. What I understand reading the paper and the code is that even if I don't need to retrain the model with kernelSHAP I need to recalculate the predictions for each coalition z to obtain f(h(z))

Answer (score 1):

The [original paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7062-a-unified-approach-to-interpreting-model-predictions.pdf) which introduced the concept of SHAP proves that SHAP values can be attained for any model by using a weighted linear regression, a method which the paper calls KernelSHAP. This reduces the computational complexity of attaining SHAP values.

As the other answer by Michael M suggests, the shap package offers great implementations of KernelSHAP and other estimation methods depending on your model.

One caveat to note with Kernel SHAP or other regression based SHAP value estimators, is that the values estimated from these regressions may not be the true SHAP values, and you can essentially re-run KernelSHAP on multiple samples, which would reduce the variance of your SHAP value estimates from KernelSHAp

One last suggestion is you could use regularization to get the number of features in your model down to a number at which the calculation of exact SHAP values would be computationally feasible.

Answer (score 0):

For a brute force exact SHAP, you even need 2 to the power of 100 models to calculate SHAP. Fortunately, there are good abbreviations like KernelSHAP and especially treeSHAP for tree-based models. The [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) package offers excellent implementations of these for Python.